# Setting LinkButton OnClick event to method in a ClassLibrary

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, methods, webforms

I have an `<asp:LinkButton>` that when clicked calls a method in my class library, but to get this to work I have had to fudge it by first going via a method in the `.aspx.cs` file for the page.

**myPage.aspx**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="foo" CommandArgument="myCommandArguments"></asp:LinkButton>
```

**myPage.aspx.cs**

```
protected void foo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myClassLibrary x = new myClassLibrary();
    x.doStuff(sender, e);
}
```

**myClassLibrary.cs**

```
public void doStuff(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Is there a way I can cut out the middle step and go directly to the method in the ClassLibrary?

Comment: One objective of having a class library is to do just like that. But you should not have `(object sender, EventArgs e)` inside your class library.

Comment: @mshsayem thanks for your response - the link button is for displaying help text associated with particular controls and will be replicated across all pages in my application. I was hoping I wouldn't have to do the middle step for every page for ease of maintenance later. Are you saying that this is the only way?

Comment: Then it (the linkbutton) should be in a _master_ page, or it should be inside a `UserControl`.